# Computing material derivated of tensor quantity

Tags: finite-volume, tensor

I would like to compute the material derivated of a tensor quantity, in the context of the finite volume method (FVM):

The equation is:

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} \textbf{T}}{\mathrm{d} t} = \frac{\partial \textbf{T}}{\partial t} + \vec{v} \cdot \nabla \textbf{T} = \underbrace{\frac{\partial \textbf{T}}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot \left(\textbf{T} \vec{v}\right) - \textbf{T} \left(\nabla \cdot \vec{v}\right)}_{is \: this \: true \:  for \: tensors?}
$$

I am thinking of solving this by solving each component entry in the tensor. Is this the correct procedure? In python, I used to solve this with `solve_ivp` but that considers a moving reference frame and in the FVM the frame is stationary.

Any tricks/things to be aware of when solving for a tensor quantity?

Comment: You may want to look up Lie derivatives and objective rates to get a feel for possible correct expressions.  Kelly's notes are reasonably good: https://pkel015.connect.amazon.auckland.ac.nz/SolidMechanicsBooks/Part_III/Chapter_2_Kinematics/Kinematics_of_CM_12_Pull_Back_Lie_Derivative.pdf

Answer (score 2):

No, the right-hand side of your equation is not valid. I will assume that $\mathbf{T}$ is a second-order tensor. If that's the case we need that the time derivative is second-order. The factor $\nabla \mathbf{T}$ gives you a third-order quantity that is later turned into a second-order one via projection over $v$. Now, the factor $\mathbf{T} v$ is a vector and is turned into a scalar after applying the divergence.

I would say that a trick might be to write the expression in index notation.

Comment: I think whether it's valid or not depends on what the notation is supposed to mean. If $\mathbf{T}v$ is the outer product $\mathbf{T}\otimes v$, which has rank equal to $\text{rank}(\mathbf{T}) + \text{rank}(v)$, then I think it's correct, but your answer assumes that it means the contraction of $\mathbf{T}$ with $v$ along some index. Either way I agree that writing it in index notation will probably help.

Comment: @DanielShapero, you are right. I assumed that the OP meant the contraction.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. To be honest I do not know if it is a contraction. For a scalar quantity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_derivative, and from the divergence identity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities. The expression holds for scalar quantities, and I have also seen it applied to vector quantities. To 2nd order tensor, I do not know ...

Comment: $ \nabla \cdot (s \vec {v}) = s (\nabla \cdot \vec{v}) + \vec{v} \cdot \nabla s$

$ \Leftrightarrow  \nabla \cdot (s \vec {v}) - s (\nabla \cdot \vec{v})=   \vec{v} \cdot \nabla s $